# Is there any way to logically partition data in Cosmos Db while quering them? like you can do with hashing and modulo functions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to run set of long-lasting data processing activities that take data from certain cosmos db container. I do not see a field in the container that could help me to spread the load more or less evenly among azure functions. I wonder if there is any hash function that lets me do a classical partitioning with mod function, let's say I decide to run like 10 activitties from orchestrator and query data like

`select * from c where hash(c.id) % 10 = {functionNumber}`.

I know it will do a full scan in each of 10 functions, but it's Ok, evenly spread load is more important in the case. It's long lasting not due to volume of data, but due to complexity of data processing

Comment: What is your collection currently partitioned on? Will the data processing be accessing a large proportion of the documents in the collection? How many physical partitions is your collection currently distributed over? Depending on the answers to these you could use a Cosmos triggered function as this uses the change feed and can process physical partitions in parallel

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're attempting to do but... as @MartinSmith mentioned, Change Feed might be an option for you (and allows for multiple readers). There is no magical hash function though. Maybe look into distributed processing engines such as Spark?

Comment: That said: unfortunately this question is off-topic as written, as it's fairly broad and opinion-soliciting (there really is no single objectively-right answer to this).

Comment: currently it's partitioned by id which is GUID. I'm not sure how many physical partitions are there, I can't control it, it's Cosmos Db in Azure, Azure decides how many physical partitions to create. Even if I knew there are let's say 5, I'm not sure I have an access to it in sql, and also it can change in time. 
I'm attempting to let each of like 10 azure functions read its own slice of data of a single container, not overlapping and evenly distributed slices. I do not think it's a broad question: It's either such Cosmos SQL feature exists or not. Thanks

Comment: Well actually I was able to find solution utilizing just modulo function and _ts which is timestamp in Cosmos Db, so I think it's Ok in replace of hash() function, like 5th activity out of 10: `SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE (root["_ts"] % 10) = 5)`
So I'm closing the question then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to hash by field which is not seemingly part of Cosmos SQL I decided to use modulo function and _ts which is timestamp in Cosmos Db

as an example, 5th activity out of 10 total will query data like this: `SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE (root["_ts"] % 10) = 5)`